# Add a filter for many to many in Laravel Backpack?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have a many to many relation between `product` and `study` models. I want to add a filter to get all the products that the `name` is like the `value` of the `filter`.
i tried my code below but i'm don't get the result i want  :

```js
$this->crud->addFilter([
            'type'  => 'text',
            'name'  => 'products',
            'label' => 'Produits'
        ],
            false,
            function($value) {
                Study::with('products')->whereHas('products', function($q) use($value) {
                    $q->whereIn('name', $value);
                })->get();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```php
$q->whereIn('name', $value);
```

Try this:

```php
$q->where("name", "like", "%{$value}%");
```

[Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)